# Build GNU Guile 3.0.4 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

How to build GNU Guile 3.0.4 on Ubuntu?

Some dependencies seem to be missing in ubuntu.

https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/download/

This does not work.

```
apt-get install guile-3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This dependencies were missing.

```
sudo apt install libgc-dev libgmp-dev libffi-dev libunistring-dev
./configure
make
sudo make install
```